# API for CreateDate for AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

Is there an API that returns the create date of an asset created on AWS? I could only see a launch date but not a create date (in `$ aws ec2 describe-instances`). The launch time changes every time the state (start/stopped/terminated) of the asset is changed.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/

Comment: yeah wasn't looking for cloudtrail. wanted something with an endpoint. thanks!

Comment: CloudTrail has an API

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no create date associated with an EC2 instance.  Only the launch time.

If you are using CloudTrail, you can look for launch events and look at the create time associated with the event.